# XML with elements of the same name

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How do I edit the data in each Address Line, since they all have the same name?

```
    <StructuredAddress>
      <AddressLine></AddressLine>
      <AddressLine></AddressLine>
      <AddressLine></AddressLine>
    </StructuredAddress>
```

My code so far, which doesn't work, is this.  How do I isolate each AddressLine indivisually and insert the appropriate data?

```
     XElement StructuredAddress = PatientAddress.Descendants("StructuredAddress").First();
     StructuredAddress.Element("AddresLine").Value = cc.address1;
     StructuredAddress.Element("AddresLine").Value = cc.address2;
     StructuredAddress.Element("AddresLine").Value = cc.address3;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, but just put an identifier in front of "AddressLine"; something like "AddressLine1"?

Comment: The xml cannot be changed, I have to work with that template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to access each `<AddressLine>` using it's index :

```
XElement StructuredAddress = PatientAddress.Descendants("StructuredAddress").First();
var address = StructuredAddress.Elements("AddresLine").ToList();
address[0].Value = cc.address1;
address[1].Value = cc.address2;
address[2].Value = cc.address3;
```

Comment: You need a `.Value` after `address[0]`, but works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate them which will present them in ordinal order:

```
foreach (var addressLine in StructuredAddress.Elements("AddressLine"))
{
    addressLine.Value = ...
}
```

Or by index;

```
var lines = StructuredAddress.Elements("AddressLine").ToList();
lines[0].Value = "...";
```